# Manipulating CSS with JQuery

Tags: javascript, css

This may be a beginner question..

I'm trying to create a shopping list app that allows me to check and un-check items as well as remove items. I have an `<li>` with the `id = "list"`. I also have a button inside that `<li>` with the `class= "remove"` (so when I click on it, it will remove the entire list)...So far I have it working so when I click the words turn gray. How would I target this so when I unclick the checkbox it goes back to normal?

note: I'm using an input type check-box, instead of a button.

```
 $('#list').click(function() { 
    $( this ).css( "color", "gray" );
    $( ".remove").css("background-color", "gray" );
   });
});
```

This is the HTML :

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Awesome Shopping List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="app-container">
        <div class="top-nav">
            <h1>My Awesome Shopping List</h1>
                <input type="text" id="message" value="Enter item..">
            <button class="add-button" type="button">Add</button>
        </div>
        <div class="main-list">
        <div class="top-labels">
            <h2>Items</h2>
            <h2>Price</h2>
            <h2>Amount</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="messages">
          <ul class="items">
          <li id="list"><input type="checkbox" id="check">Item One<input type="text" class="price" value=""><input type="text" class="amount" value=""><button type="button" class="remove">x</button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
            <div class="total-container">
                <h3>Total</h3>
                <input type="text" value="">
            </div>  
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I have a Link to the online project [here](http://codepen.io/froinunez/pen/Lvgkm).

Comment: First of all you'll be better off switching classes that represent the states that an element can be in, and keeping colours and backgrounds in the CSS only.

Comment: Can you include some of your HTML also, it would help others in answering your question.

Comment: I grasp the concept, please provide some html or Jsfiddle, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use .toggleClass() and define two classes with the css defined.

```
$( "#list" ).click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass( "class1", "class2" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to toggle the visibility / availability of something, i would recommend creating 2 different classes.

1 for normal list / list item e.g class="normal"
2 for removing / disabling lists / list items.

e.g list item before clicking would be like

when you click a button and remove the list item, then you add the removed class

and in css, removed class will override the text color and visibility settings for normal list item.

when you want to re-enable the item, all you do, is remove the "removed" class.

$( ".someitem").removeClass("removed")

Answer (score 0):

First, I would strongly suggest using CSS classes as opposed to manipulating CSS attributes directly. More to the point though, in your handler you can determine whether the box is now checked using

```
$(this).is(':checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not personally a fan of `toggleClass()` as it doesn't care about the current state of the checkbox to work, which may not match up with your expectations.

I recommend basing your CSS changes on the state of the checkbox itself.

```
var checkboxSelector = '#list input[type=checkbox]'; // or whatever it is for you.
$(checkboxSelector).on('click', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
     $(this).css('color','grey');
  } else {
     $(this).css('color','white');
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Without out seeing your HTML I would say this may be what you're looking for. If you provide me with your html, I could help you target it more efficiently.  Right now it's important to note that you may be applying styles to List Items you might not be intending to.

```
$('#list input[type="checkbox]').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).value()) {
        $(this).css("color", "black");
        $(".remove").css("background-color", "white");
    }
});
```